# LinqDataSource Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have quite a complex LinqDataSource that I'm trying to setup. I've been able to write part of the Linq for it but am unsure how to convert this to LINQDataSource syntax or whether it is even possible. It looks like this.

```
ConfigDetails.Where (cd => 
AuthProductOwners
   .Where (o => (o.LoginID == @LoginID ))
   .Select (o => o.AuthProductOwnerGroups).Contains(cd.AuthProductOwnerGroups))
```

The table structure is a AuthProductOwnerGroup can have many ConfigDetails and also many AuthProductOwners.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question completely, but I guess you find it difficult to transfer your Linq statement to the datasource. Is that corrrect?

If so: The easiest solution is to create a simple Linq datasource and implement the linqdatasource selecting event and put your query there.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.selecting.aspx

Comment: Yes thats essentially the problem. I'm not proficient in LINQ to be able to convert the statement to the LINQDataSource. Thanks for the link I'll have a look.